# Binding Properties.Settings to Textbox fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I would like to define a key & value in Settings.settings and bind the value *by declaration* in the XAML (not in the code behind by command).

Here's what I've been trying in vain:

1. Create a WPF project "Exp1" with Visual Studio Express 2010.
2. Set one key named "TextFromSettings" to the value "Some Text from Setting".
3. Add the attribute `xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Exp1.Properties;assembly=Exp1"` to the  tag.
4. Add `Text="{Binding Path=TextFromSettings, Mode=TwoWay, Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}}"` to the  tag

Now, the preview window shows the text, however, the compiler fails:

*"Error 1   Cannot find the type 'Settings'. Note that type names are case sensitive."*

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Also make sure that the access modifier is set to public in the settings editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `;assembly=Exp1` it's not allowed for references to the current assembly.

If anything it should be `;assembly=`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx).

> **assembly** can be omitted if the **clr-namespace** referenced is being defined within the same assembly as the application code that is referencing the custom classes. Or, an equivalent syntax for this case is to specify **assembly=**, with no string token following the equals sign.